# Model Binding To List Of Objects In ASP.NET MVC with RadioButton

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I view list data and I want to edit some field
[example as image, list view data, and edit it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqI74.png)

i have a field (ex:choosed_value with some value 1,2,3,4,5)
in view, i use radiobutton to get value from choosed_value,
but when i submit to save, i can't get value choosed from radiobutton,
field 'content' saved ok, field 'choosed_value' not save.

my code

in view

view radiobutton

```
@for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
{
   <td>     
       @Html.RadioButton(Model[i].ID.ToString(), Model[i].choosed_value,Model[i].choosed_value == j) ? true : false )
   </td>
}
```

if choosed_value = 1 then radiobutton with value = 1, checked = true

in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<Content> contents)
{
     DEMOEntities DbContent = new DEMOEntities();
     foreach (Content cont in contents)
     {
         Content Existed_Cont = DbContent.Contents.Find(cont.ID);
         Existed_Cont.Content = cont.Content;
         Existed_Cont.choosed_value = cont.choosed_value;
     }
     DbContent.SaveChanges();
 }
```

please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

I think your radiobutton names are incorrect (first param of Html.RadioButton).
The result input name in browser should not be ID, it should be like [0].choosed_value for correct model binding on POST.

```
@for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
{
   <td>     
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model[i].choosed_value, ...)
   </td>
}
```

instead of

```
@for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
{
   <td>     
       @Html.RadioButton(Model[i].ID.ToString(), Model[i].choosed_value,Model[i].choosed_value == j) ? true : false )
   </td>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the browser dev-tools to see what is actually passed as data to your controller. There should be some fields with the name 'contents' or the model-binder cannot pick them up.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we shouldnt make a database call from action method directly.
Now your ViewModel's list should be of type `List<SelectListItem>`, in that way you can get the "selected" item's value straight forward.